# When attempting to formData to an express js the server is not recognizing multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to upload form-data to an express server.
On my express js server I have the following:

```
router.post('/uploads/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body);
  const title = req.body.title;
  const file = req.file;
});
```

I send back the req.body to see that it hit the url propperly.
When I use the following:

```
const response = await fetch('https://example.com/uploads/1234', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(form) });
const responseData = await response.json();

console.log(responseData);
```

I get the response of the FormData converted to json.
However when I run it like this:

```
const file = fs.createReadStream(`${desktopDir}/ai2html-output/home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg`);
const title = 'My file fsf';

const form = new FormData();
form.append('title', title);
form.append('file', file);

    const response = await fetch('https://example.com/uploads/1234', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      body: form });
    const responseData = await response.json();
```

Then the return is an empty object:
{}

Is there something I have to setup on my express server to receive the form-data?  Do I need some type of middleware?

Also here is my request header response from the server:

```
:method: POST
:path: /uploads/1234
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 17
content-type: multipart/form-data
origin: file://
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I have to setup on my express server to receive the
> form-data?

Yes, To handle `multipart/form-data` in your *Express* server, you must configure a **middleware**.
For instance [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) library.

### Demo:

**Server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
app = express();
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
//----------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------- middleware
app.post("/uploads/:id", upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
  const title = req.body.title;
  console.log(req.file);
/*
Output of req.file:
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'test.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: '61d00f21b9813bdcb326082b41b58eb3',
  path: 'uploads\\61d00f21b9813bdcb326082b41b58eb3',
  size: 0
}
*/
  res.json({ msg: `file ${title} uploaded successfully!` });
});
app.listen(1234, () => {
  console.log("app is running on 1234");
});
```

**Upload.js**

```js
var fs = require("fs");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var FormData = require("form-data");

const form = new FormData();
const title = "Test";
const file = fs.createReadStream(`./test.jpg`);
form.append("title", title);
form.append("file", file);

(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1234/uploads/1234", {
      method: "POST",
      //   headers: {
      //     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      //   },
      body: form,
    });
    const responseData = await response.json();
    console.log(responseData); // you got { msg: 'file Test uploaded successfully!' }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

*Note:* the Fetch would set the headers automatically, So just Take away header `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`.

If you want to save the file uploaded into a specific folder "uploads/" with its title came with **req.body.title**, Add this configuration to **multer**:

```js
const path = require("path");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    cb(null, title + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Comment: I'm using fetch inside of a client called Adobe CEP.  It converts the content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 and then the req.body.title is undefined.  When I do the multipart-formdata I get Multipart: Boundary not found any ideas? @XMehdi01

Comment: So how do you use  fs.createReadStream inside client side?

Comment: It runs on node so it works but I think it doesn't automatically set headers for some reason.