# HTTP 409 Conflict on POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am new to Web Development so please don't judge me here:
So, I am building a website where when I am sending a POST request, I am receiving an 409 error. Below is the code:

**//Server side:**
**(index.js)**

```
...
app.use("/jobs", jobRoutes);
...
```

**(models/Job.js)**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    clientId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Client',
      required: true
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 5,
    },
    categoryId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category',
      required: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 5,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Job = mongoose.model("Job", jobSchema);

export default Job;
```

**(controllers/jobs.js)**

```
import Job from "../models/Job.js";

/* CREATE */
export const postJob = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { clientId, title, categoryId, description } = req.body;
    const newJob = new Job({
      clientId,
      title,
      categoryId,
      description,
    });
    await newJob.save();

    const jobs = await Job.find();
    res.status(201).json(jobs);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};


/* READ */
export const getJobs = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const jobs = await Job.find();
    res.status(200).json(jobs);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

**(routes/jobs.js)**

```
import express from "express";
import { postJob, getJobs } from "../controllers/jobs.js";
import { verifyToken } from "../middleware/auth.js";

const router = express.Router();

/* CREATE */
router.post("/", verifyToken, postJob);

/* READ */
router.get("/", verifyToken, getJobs);

export default router;
```

**//Client Side:**
**(components/JobsWidget.jsx)**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setJobs, setCategories } from "../state";
import JobWidget from "./JobWidget";

const JobsWidget = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { users, jobs, categories, token, userMode } = useSelector(
    (state) => state
  );

  const getJobs = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/jobs", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(setJobs({ jobs: data }));
  };

  const getCategories = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/categories", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(setCategories({ categories: data }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categories.length < 1) getCategories();
    getJobs();
  }, [userMode]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <>
      {jobs.length > 0 ? (
        jobs.map(
          ({ _id, clientId, title, categoryId, description, createdAt }) => {
            const user = users.find((usr) => usr._id === clientId);
            const category = categories.find((cat) => cat._id === categoryId);
            let date = new Date(createdAt);
            date = date.toLocaleDateString();

            return (
              <JobWidget
                key={_id}
                jobId={_id}
                title={title}
                category={category.title}
                description={description}
                clientId={user._id}
                clientPicture={user.picturePath}
                clientName={user.fullName}
                date={date}
              />
            );
          }
        )
      ) : (
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "2rem" }}>
          No jobs to show
        </p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default JobsWidget;
```

**(components/PostJobWidget.jsx)**

```
import {
  Box,
  Modal,
  Typography,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  TextField,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  useTheme,
  Button,
  useMediaQuery,
} from "@mui/material";
import FlexBetween from "./FlexBetween";
import WidgetWrapper from "./WidgetWrapper";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { setJobs } from "../state";

const postJobSchema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup.string().required("required"),
  description: yup.string().required("required"),
});

const initialValuesPostJob = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
};

const PostJobWidget = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [sort, setSort] = useState("");
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const { palette } = useTheme();
  const { _id } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
  const userMode = useSelector((state) => state.userMode);
  const categories = useSelector((state) => state.categories);
  const isNonMobileScreens = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1000px)");

  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setCategory("");
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleSort = (event) => {
    setSort(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleFilter = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleCategory = (event) => {
    setCategory(event.target.value);
  };

  const postJob = async (values) => {
    const { title, description } = values;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("clientId", _id);
    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("categoryId", category);
    formData.append("description", description);

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/jobs`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      body: formData,
    });

    const jobs = await response.json();
    dispatch(setJobs({ jobs }));
    handleClose();
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [userMode]);

  return (
    <WidgetWrapper>
      <FlexBetween gap={"1rem"}>
        <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 80, width: "20%" }}>
          <InputLabel id="sort-label">Sort</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="sort-label"
            id="sort-select"
            value={sort}
            label="Sort"
            onChange={handleSort}
          >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Date</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Job Status</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 100, width: "30%" }}>
          <InputLabel id="filter-label">Filter</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="filter-label"
            id="filter-select"
            value={filter}
            label="Filter"
            onChange={handleFilter}
          >
            {categories.map((category) => (
              <MenuItem key={category._id} value={category._id}>
                {category.title}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        {userMode === "client" && (
          <>
            <Button
              onClick={handleOpen}
              sx={{
                color: palette.background.alt,
                backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
                borderRadius: "2rem",
                width: "6rem",
                height: "3rem",
                "&:hover": {
                  color: palette.primary.main,
                },
              }}
            >
              POST JOB
            </Button>
            <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "50%",
                  left: "50%",
                  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                  width: isNonMobileScreens ? "24rem" : "20rem",
                  bgcolor: "white",
                  border: "2px solid #000",
                  borderRadius: "1rem",
                  boxShadow: 24,
                  p: 4,
                }}
              >
                <Typography
                  fontSize={"1rem"}
                  fontWeight={"600"}
                  marginBottom={"1rem"}
                  textAlign={"center"}
                >
                  Post Job
                </Typography>
                <Formik
                  onSubmit={postJob}
                  initialValues={initialValuesPostJob}
                  validationSchema={postJobSchema}
                >
                  {({
                    values,
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleBlur,
                    handleChange,
                    handleSubmit,
                  }) => (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <Box
                        display="grid"
                        gap="20px"
                        gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                      >
                        <TextField
                          label="Title"
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          value={values.title}
                          name="title"
                          error={
                            Boolean(touched.title) && Boolean(errors.title)
                          }
                          helperText={touched.title && errors.title}
                          sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                        />
                        <FormControl sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}>
                          <InputLabel id="category-label">Category</InputLabel>
                          <Select
                            labelId="category-label"
                            id="category-select"
                            value={category}
                            label="Category"
                            onChange={handleCategory}
                            required
                          >
                            {categories.map((category) => (
                              <MenuItem key={category._id} value={category._id}>
                                {category.title}
                              </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        <TextField
                          label="Description"
                          multiline
                          maxRows={4}
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          value={values.description}
                          name="description"
                          error={
                            Boolean(touched.description) &&
                            Boolean(errors.description)
                          }
                          helperText={touched.description && errors.description}
                          sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                        />
                      </Box>

                      <Box>
                        <Button
                          fullWidth
                          type="submit"
                          sx={{
                            m: "2rem 0",
                            p: "1rem",
                            backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
                            color: palette.background.alt,
                            "&:hover": { color: palette.primary.main },
                          }}
                          variant="outlined"
                        >
                          POST NOW
                        </Button>
                      </Box>
                    </form>
                  )}
                </Formik>
              </Box>
            </Modal>
          </>
        )}
      </FlexBetween>
    </WidgetWrapper>
  );
};

export default PostJobWidget;
```

I don't understand where I am making a mistake, can someone please give me any clue where or what I might be doing wrong? This is the error that I am getting:

```
Error: Job validation failed: clientId: Path `clientId` is required., title: Path `title` is required., categoryId: Path `categoryId` is required., description: Path `description` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:50:26)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:806:19)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:365:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2273:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2135:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:340:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:377:61)
    at postJob (file:///D:/SIBAU/BSCS-VIII/Project-II/nasrp/server/controllers/jobs.js:18:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: {
    clientId: ValidatorError: Path `clientId` is required.
        at validate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1346:13)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:7)
        at D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2905:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'clientId',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    title: ValidatorError: Path `title` is required.
        at validate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1346:13)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:7)
        at D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2905:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'title',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    categoryId: ValidatorError: Path `categoryId` is required.
        at validate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1346:13)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:7)
        at D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2905:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'categoryId',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    description: ValidatorError: Path `description` is required.
        at validate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1346:13)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:7)
        at D:\SIBAU\BSCS-VIII\Project-II\nasrp\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2905:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'description',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'Job validation failed'
}
```

Comment: Could you share the error message that is being printed? Adding a console.log in the catch of the post job function in the jobs.js file inside the controllers folder might help you understand the error. Please make sure to share the error printed so that I can help you!

Comment: This is the error:
Error: Job validation failed: clientId: Path `clientId` is required., title: Path `title` is required., categoryId: Path `categoryId` is required., description: Path `description` is required.

Comment: Where are you exactly calling the POST api in the client side? It seems like none of the required fields are being sent to the backend.

Comment: Are you using JSON as the way to send data in your server?

Comment: I am sending key-value pairs using FormData(). You can see this in PostJobWidget.js

Comment: Try checking out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158415/when-attempting-to-formdata-to-an-express-js-the-server-is-not-recognizing-multi

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped. I solved the issue as follows:

**(components/PostJobWidget.jsx)**

```
  const postJob = async (values) => {
    const { title, description } = values;

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/jobs`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        clientId: _id,
        title: title,
        categoryId: category,
        description: description,
      }),
    });

    const jobs = await response.json();
    dispatch(setJobs({ jobs }));
    handleClose();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the object as JSON to the API.

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/jobs`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      body: {clientId: _id, title: title, categoryId: category, description: description},
    });
```

Comment: didn't work :(
Still same issue

Comment: Can you print the body that you are sending in the client and check it's contents to see if it is a backend issue?

Comment: So, if I am doing this:
if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "No data provided" });
    }

It tells data is not being sent to the server? So where might be the issue?

Comment: Can you print the contents of the form data that you are sending in the body from the client side and share it? Also try to give the link I added as a comment above a look

Comment: If I print formData after appending the values, it prints an empty object but when I print the values individually they are there.

Comment: Did you try using the get function? Like this: formData.get('clientId')

Comment: Can you also try to specify the content type of the data in the body in the headers. By that I mean that you should add another header called 'Content-Type' and set it to be "multipart/form-data".

Comment: formData.get() do give me values.

Comment: "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", is also not working :(